# Test2 Array Initialization Error

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, indexoutofboundsexception

My class `Test2` has a method to return area. It accepts a variable number of argument (Varargs) and I am trying to add alternative Varargs into the array `lengthOfSide` and `breadthOfSide` using a `for` loop but I am getting an `ArrayOutofBoundException`. Why am I getting this and how do I fix it?

```
class Test2 {
    public double returnArea(double... corner){
        double[] lengthOfSide = {};
        double[] breadthOfSide = {};
        int i = 0;

        for(double x : corner){
            lengthOfSide[i]  = x;
            breadthOfSide[i] = x;

            System.out.println(lengthOfSide[i]);
            System.out.println(breadthOfSide[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test2 total = new Test2();
        total.returnArea(34.2,22.3,332.2,223.3,22.4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java arrays have a fixed length. You currently create two arrays of length `0`. Change

```
double[] lengthOfSide = {};
double[] breadthOfSide = {};
```

to something like

```
double[] lengthOfSide = new double[corner.length];
double[] breadthOfSide = new double[corner.length];
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are basically trying to modify an existing array which is not allowed...**

**Arrays in java are fixed sized** and you can't modify them after you have created them.

basically,

```
double[] lengthOfSide = {};
double[] breadthOfSide = {};
```

this lines created an array for you (empty array).
where as in loop you are trying to assign a value to index in array that does not exist.

```
 lengthOfSide[i]  = x;
 breadthOfSide[i] = x;
```

result is **excetion**.

if You want to achieve what i guess is right you should initialize it to some length you want ie. corner.length

so it should be,

```
double[] lengthOfSide = new double[corner.length];
double[] breadthOfSide = new double[corner.length];
```

also if you still want to go with the same flow try considering using [arraylist](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwitgcvp0trTAhUJo48KHX0vDA0QFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FArrayList.html&usg=AFQjCNE8kASi8jTGZ0mxhyh3QlNJbgUGMA) for purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the length of array when you create one. And after this you can't change array length.  There are 2 arrays with length of 0 in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the help